# Outlook create a button like 'Private'

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-office, outlook-2010

I want to create a button like the 'Private' button when creating a new appointment/meeting. So that the button freeze in the mouse hover style when it gets clicked.

I create the button in the VBA project like this:

```
Set objCBC = objCB.Controls.Add(Type:= --WHICHTYPE--, _
                                Temporary:=True)
```

So does anybody know which type of button should be applied here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command bars were deprecated. You need to use the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) instead. Unfortunately Outlook doesn't allows to customize the Fluent UI with VBA, you need to develop an add-in instead. You can read more about the new UI in the following series of articles in MSDN:

1. [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
2. [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
3. [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

See the **toggleButton** control in the list of available controls.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. Is there anywhere a good API? Because I can't get the onAction function to run. Or I would need to get the state of the toggle button when the user press 'Save'